# Restart Yes or no with this type of code in Python

Tags: python

My code is below. The code at the end to restart the function ( yes or no ), doesn't work. I have checked many tutorials and I can't see what's wrong.

```
#sys
import sys

# cette fonction est la puissance 5 d'un entier donné en paramètre
def somme(x):
    return x**5
# Le produit de deux entiers données en paramètre moins leur somme.
def produit(x, y):
   return (x * y)-(x+y)
# Le produit de trois entiers données en paramètre au carré
def carre(x,y,z):
  return (x*y*z)**2


print("Sélectionner votre opération")
print("1.Puissance 5 d'un entier")
print("2.Deux entiers moins leur somme")
print("3. trois produit au carré")
choix = input("Enter votre choix (1/2/3): ")
if choix == '1':
    num1 = float(input("Enter 1er numero: "))
    print("votre rep est",somme(num1))
elif choix == '2':
    num1=int(input("Enrer votre premier nombre : "))
    num2=int(input("Entrer votre deuxième nombre: "))
    print("votre rep est",produit(num1,num2))
elif choix == '3': 
    num1=int(input("Enrer votre premier nombre : "))
    num2=int(input("Entrer votre deuxième nombre: "))
    num3=int(input("Entrer votre troisième nombre: "))
    print("Le résultat est : ",carre(num1,num2,num3))

else:
 print("Tu fais quoi là jeune homme?")

while True:
        answer = input('Run again? (y/n): ')
        if answer in ('y', 'n'):
            break
        print ('Invalid input.')
else:
 print ('Goodbye')
exit()
```

Comment: Why do you want to repeat `'Run again? (y/n): '` for infinite number of times and break for `'y'` and `'n'`? If you look closely, what I assume you want to repeat is the choice conditions and you might want to break only for `'n'` input.

Comment: Put the code you want to run again in a function and then call it from the `while` loop until the user enters `n`

Comment: What do you mean by `don't want to work`? What is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior? Also the formatting of the code. in particular white spaces, seems to be inconsistent. Please fix it, because that affects the behavior of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try:

```
import sys

# cette fonction est la puissance 5 d'un entier donné en paramètre
def somme(x):
    return x**5
# Le produit de deux entiers données en paramètre moins leur somme.


def produit(x, y):
    return (x * y)-(x+y)
# Le produit de trois entiers données en paramètre au carré


def carre(x, y, z):
    return (x*y*z)**2

def loop():
    print("Sélectionner votre opération")
    print("1.Puissance 5 d'un entier")
    print("2.Deux entiers moins leur somme")
    print("3. trois produit au carré")
    choix = input("Enter votre choix (1/2/3): ")
    if choix == '1':
        num1 = float(input("Enter 1er numero: "))
        print("votre rep est", somme(num1))
    elif choix == '2':
        num1 = int(input("Enrer votre premier nombre : "))
        num2 = int(input("Entrer votre deuxième nombre: "))
        print("votre rep est", produit(num1, num2))
    elif choix == '3':
        num1 = int(input("Enrer votre premier nombre : "))
        num2 = int(input("Entrer votre deuxième nombre: "))
        num3 = int(input("Entrer votre troisième nombre: "))
        print("Le résultat est : ", carre(num1, num2, num3))

    else:
        print("Tu fais quoi là jeune homme?")

loop()

while True:
    answer = input('Run again? (y/n): ')
    if answer == 'y':
        loop()
    elif answer == 'n':
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid input.')
else:
    print('Goodbye')

sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restart the calculations, you need to put them **inside** a loop:

```
# cette fonction est la puissance 5 d'un entier donné en paramètre
def somme(x):
    return x**5
# Le produit de deux entiers données en paramètre moins leur somme.
def produit(x, y):
   return (x * y)-(x+y)
# Le produit de trois entiers données en paramètre au carré
def carre(x,y,z):
  return (x*y*z)**2

while True: # this is the main loop
  print("Sélectionner votre opération")
  print("1.Puissance 5 d'un entier")
  print("2.Deux entiers moins leur somme")
  print("3. trois produit au carré")
  choix = input("Enter votre choix (1/2/3): ")
  if choix == '1':
    num1 = float(input("Enter 1er numero: "))
    print("votre rep est",somme(num1))
  elif choix == '2':
    num1=int(input("Enrer votre premier nombre : "))
    num2=int(input("Entrer votre deuxième nombre: "))
    print("votre rep est",produit(num1,num2))
  elif choix == '3': 
    num1=int(input("Enrer votre premier nombre : "))
    num2=int(input("Entrer votre deuxième nombre: "))
    num3=int(input("Entrer votre troisième nombre: "))
    print("Le résultat est : ",carre(num1,num2,num3))
  else:
    print("Tu fais quoi là jeune homme?")

  while True: # this is another loop, just to check the answer
    answer = input('Run again? (y/n): ')
    if answer == 'n':
      print('Goodbye')
      sys.exit()
    elif answer == 'y':
      break # exit the inner loop, but repeat the outer one
    else:
      print('Invalid input.')
```